# EF6 code first - stored procedure hierarchy query with multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-6

I'm quite new with EF6 and I would like to code this stored procedure with EF. I started playing around with the navigations properties and the ".Includes" but this is a bit too complex for me.

Some explanations about this : I have users with a *RoleSetId* assigned. A *RoleSetId* is linked to a *ModuleGroup*. A *ModuleGroup* contains *Modules* so the user can have access to theses *Modules* based on his *RoleSetId*. He can also access *Modules* from child *ModuleGroups*. So a *ModuleGroup* can contain *Modules* but it can also contain *ModuleGroups*.

Here is the stored procedure which gets the *Id* from *ModuleGroup* based on the *RoleSetId* and then, do a recursive query to get all *ModuleGroups* which are available for the *RoleSetId*, then return the *Modules* contained in the selected *ModuleGroups*:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetModules] @RoleSetId int
AS

    DECLARE @id INT
    SET @id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM ModuleGroup WHERE RoleSetId = @RoleSetId);

    WITH groups AS (
        SELECT mgg.ModuleGroupId, mgg.ModuleGroupSubGroupId
        FROM [dbo].[ModuleGroupSubGroup] mgg
        WHERE ModuleGroupId = @id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT mgg2.ModuleGroupId, mgg2.ModuleGroupSubGroupId
        FROM [dbo].[ModuleGroupSubGroup] mgg2
        JOIN groups g ON g.ModuleGroupSubGroupId = mgg2.ModuleGroupId
    )
    SELECT m.*
    FROM Module m
    INNER JOIN ModuleGroupModule mgm ON mgm.ModuleId = m.InternalId
    WHERE mgm.ModuleGroupId IN (SELECT g.ModuleGroupSubGroupId FROM groups g) OR mgm.ModuleGroupId = @id
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Here are my tables (simplified) :

```
[Table("ModuleGroup")]
public class ModuleGroup : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ModuleGroupModule> ModuleGroupModules { get; set; }

    public int RoleSetId { get; set; }
}

[Table("ModuleGroupSubGroup")]
public class ModuleGroupSubGroup : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ModuleGroupId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ModuleGroup))]
    public int ModuleGroupSubGroupId { get; set; }

    public ModuleGroup ModuleGroup { get; set; }
}


[Table("ModuleGroupModule")]
public class ModuleGroupModule : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ModuleGroup))]
    public int ModuleGroupId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Module))]
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public Module Module { get; set; }

    public ModuleGroup ModuleGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("Module")]
public class Module : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ModuleGroupModule> ModuleGroupModules { get; set; }
}
```

To be more clear, here is the db schema :

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: LINQ doesn't have a corresponding query construct to a Recursive Common Table Expression.  You can keep using the stored procedure, or process the rows in procedural code on the client, either by fetching all the rows first, or using Lazy Loading.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of this kind of answer. As we disabled Lazy Loading on our project, I guess I'll have to get the rows first. But I have to apply another filters, my way to do it is like this : query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SPD").ToList() and then result = query.AsQueryable().Includes ....
Another way to avoid the .ToList() followed by .AsQueryable() ?